# How to apply the same awk action to all the files in a folder?

Tags: bash, awk

I had written an awk code for deleting all the lines ending in a colon from a file. But now I want to run this particular awk action on a whole folder containing similar files.

```
  awk '!/:$/' qs.txt > fin.txt
  awk '{print $3 "           " $4}' fin.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: Do you intend to send all output to fin.txt and out.txt or these file names change according to something?

Comment: Why do you have 2 separate awk commands? You know they could be combined into `awk '!/:$/{print $3 "           " $4}' qs.txt > out.txt`, right?

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your `awk` command in a loop in your shell such as `bash`.

```
myfiles=mydirectory/*.txt
for file in $myfiles
do
    b=$(basename "$file" .txt)
    awk '!/:$/' "$b.txt" > "$b.out"
done
```

EDIT: improved quoting as commenters suggested

If you like it better, you can use `"${file%.txt}"` instead of `$(basename "$file" .txt)`.

Aside: My own preference runs to `basename` just because `man basename` is easier for me than `man -P 'less -p "^   Param"' bash` (when that is the relevant heading on the particular system). Please accept this quirk of mine and let's not discuss `info` and http://linux.die.net/man/ and whatever.

Comment: That would fail for any files that contain spaces in their names. Using a var instead of just `for file in *` makes things much harder.

Comment: Yes, I agree. That's an issue. It's well trodden ground though. I think we're discussing interactive commands rather than scripting. So I'd simply suggest to be aware of the case when filenames have spaces and then go find the usual solutions. I used a var for sake of sort of indicating "your particulars go here".

Comment: Hm? Did I miss something? This fails on files with spaces because the use of `$file` and `$b` in the loop isn't quoted. The loop itself is fine. Assignments don't get pathname expanded so the glob doesn't expand until the expansion in the loop happens (which is why general recommendations are not to use unquoted variables in loops because you don't *generally* want that but in this case it works the way it was intended).

Comment: @EtanReisner you're right I misread it, I thought the original assignment was doing an `ls *`. The script still fails, of course, as well as using deprecated backticks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sed. Just run the below command on the directory in which the files you want to change was actually stored.

```
sed -i '/:$/d' *.*
```

Comment: to do a recursive replace `find . -type -f -exec sed -i '/:$/d' {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

This will create new files in an empty directory, with the same name.

```
mkdir NEWFILES
for file in `find . -name "*name_pattern*"`
do
awk '!/:$/' $file > fin.txt
awk '{print $3 "           " $4}' fin.txt > NEWFILES/$file 
done
```

After that you just need to

```
cp -fr NEWFILES/* .
```